# Python не видит смену раскладки

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, winapi

День добрый, в процессе постижения азов Python столкнулся с проблемой. Хочу видеть раскладку пользователя в реальном времени. Имею вот такой код:

```
from win32api import GetKeyboardLayout
import time

def get_lang():
    if GetKeyboardLayout() == 67699721:
        lang = 'en'
    else:
        lang = 'ru'
    return lang

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(get_lang())
```

В процессе работы скрипта обнаружил, что для Питона раскладка остается такой же, как и во время запуска программы, хотя в самой системе она меняется. В чем же дело?

Comment: Вы слишком оптимистично полагаетесь на то, что а) в системе всего два языка, и б) это русский и английский. Что если языка три? Или вместо английского - французский?

Comment: Похожий вопрос на SO: [can't get current keyboard layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379713/cant-get-current-keyboard-layout/)

Answer (score 2):

`GetKeyboardLayout()` извлекает идентификатор активной локали ввода
(ранее называвшийся раскладкой клавиатуры) для **указанного потока**.
Если параметр `idThread` равен нулю, возвращается идентификатор входной локали для активного потока.

Операционная система назначает языковой стандарт каждому потоку, изначально присваивая
"языковой стандарт системы по умолчанию", определенный `LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT`. При запуске потока в процессе, принадлежащем пользователю, операционная система назначает потоку "языковой стандарт пользователя по умолчанию". Этот языковой стандарт определяется `LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT`. Приложение может переопределить значение по умолчанию с помощью функции `SetThreadLocale`, чтобы явно задать языковой стандарт для потока.

```
from threading import Thread

layout_= GetKeyboardLayoutName() # получаем значение раскладки клавиатуры
                                 # при первом запуске программы (основного потока)


def GetLay_():
    global lay
    lay = GetKeyboardLayoutName(): # получаем значение раскладки клавиатуры
                                   # в новом потоке, тем самым получая новое 
                                   # значение
        

new_thread = Thread(target=GetLay_)


while(True):
    if not new_thread.is_alive():
        new_thread = Thread(target=GetLay_)
        new_thread.start()
        new_thread.join()

        
    if layout_ != lay:
        layout_ = lay
        print(lay)
```

Answer (score -1):

Мне интересно, как win32 API относится к "азам" питона???)))

GetKeyboardLayout если верить гуглу - выдаст код языка, хранимый в реестре и для английского (по информации того же гугла) это 00000409. И вообще зачем в питоне трогать win api???

Comment: Да, win32api хоть и сложно отнести к азам, но иногда возникает необходимость воспользоваться тем, до чего еще не вырос. По поводу вашего ответа: Если верить методу `GetKeyboardLayoutList()` из той же библиотеки, то у меня в системе два языка: `(68748313, 67699721)`. Методом тыка определяем, что 67699721 - английский. Почему так, а не 00000409?  - не знаю. Хотя я все же не думаю, что проблема в самом методе: такая проблема возникает в другой программе с другими библиотеками

Comment: Похоже, что 00000409 это то, что выдает для английской раскладки ``GetKeyboardLayoutName()``.