# Оптимизировать ветвление

Tags: python, python-3.x, оптимизация, инспекция-кода

Здравствкйте. В ожидании ответа на вопрос [про раскладку в python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/861481/python-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%83-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b8), меняю язык с английского на русский вот таким костылем:

```
if k =='q':
    return u'й'
elif k == 'w':
    return u'ц'
elif k == 'e':
    return u'у'
elif k == 'r':
    return u'к'
elif k == 't':
    return u'е'
elif k == 'y':
    return u'н'
elif k == 'u':
    return u'г'
elif k == 'i':
    return u'ш'
elif k == 'o':
    return u'щ'
elif k == 'p':
    return u'з'
elif k == '[':
    return u'х'
elif k == ']':
    return u'ъ'
elif k == 'a':
    return u'ф'
elif k == 's':
    return u'ы'
elif k == 'd':
    return u'в'
elif k == 'f':
    return u'а'
etc.... (35 elif)
```

Мне нужно оптимизировать такое большое ветвление и эффективно. Как это сделать? Сам я додумался сделать либо бинарный поиск, либо расположить символы в порядке их частоты использования в языке, но не знаю, как определить производительность каждого из способов. Помогите

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать метод [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).

```
en = r"qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'zxcvbnm,./`"
ru = r"йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю.ё"

en2ru = str.maketrans(dict(zip(en, ru)))
ru2en = str.maketrans(dict(zip(ru, en)))

print("qwerty[].".translate(en2ru))  # -> йцукенхъю
print("ывазщёю".translate(ru2en))  # -> sdfpo`.
```

P.S. Если в "карте" трансляции не найдено соответствие, символ остается неизменным, пример:

```
print("a1d3 l5".translate(en2ru))  # -> ф1в3 д5
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно значения в словарь поместить, а потом по ключу вытаскивать:

```
EN_BY_RU = {
    'q': u'й', 't': u'е',
    'w': u'ц', 'y': u'н',
    'e': u'у', 'u': u'г',
    # ...
}

# Если нужен обратный словарь:
RU_BY_EN = {v: k for k, v in EN_BY_RU.items()}


k = 'q'
print(EN_BY_RU[k])      # [] при отсутствии ключа выбросит исключение KeyError
print(EN_BY_RU.get(k))  # get при отсутствии ключа вернет None, либо указанное значение
print(EN_BY_RU.get(k, ''))  # если `k` не будет, вернем пустую строку
```

Answer (score 1):

Можете не отказываться от условий, но и возможности словаря задействовать:

```
def my_dict(k):
    return {
        k == 'q': u'й',
        k == 'w': u'ц',
        k == 'e': u'у',
        k in ['abcd']: '@',
        # ...... и т.д. и т.п.
    }[True]

print my_dict('w')
```